# Returning only a part of the string from a grep result

Tags: bash, grep

I'm using grep on text file containing some simple logs in the following form:-

```
[ABC.txt]
1=abc|2=def|3=ghi|4=hjk|5=lmn|6=opq
8=rst|9=uvx|10=wyz
.
.
.
.
```

and so on

the values for the tags 1,2,3,4 etc are different throughout the file and include special characters in some case too. Is there a way I can only  retrieve the value for the tag 4 and no other tags via GREP?

BTW,this log file is itself a result of grep .So please advice if I should redirect the output first and then apply the second grep or apply the second grep over the first one,considering it's a large file.

Comment: please show a proper [mcve] together with expected output and what you tried already. Also, giving your initial grep would help since everything may be optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe the result of grep to cut, split the fields by "|" and select the fourth field

```
[your grep command] | cut -d | -f 4
```

If you want the "4=" to be gone you can just do the same by using cut a second time but this time using "=" as a delimiter.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cut.html

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po '(?<=4=)[^|]*' ABC.txt
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)